# Kendo grid appending code to Create's inline cancel/update command buttons

Tags: grid, inline, kendo-ui

I'm not using the wrapper but I'm wondering if it's possible to add additional jscript code to the cancel and update command buttons on a new inline row which has been created?

If possible I would then add .hide to the custom create button to hide itself after being clicked and would want to show it again after clicking the inline update/cancel command buttons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily attach extra handlers to these buttons with the help of the [edit](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/grid#edit) event:

```
$(function(){
     $('#GridName').data().kendoGrid.bind('edit',function(e){
          if(e.model.isNew()){
               e.container.find('.k-grid-update').click(function(){
                    //extra update logic goes here    
               })
               e.container.find('.k-grid-cancel').click(function(){
                    //extra cancel logic goes here    
               })
          }
     })
})
```

Comment: this seems like exactly what I want so I'll try it out now

Comment: where i need to put this sample codes,within document ready funtion or anywhere else.

Comment: It depends when you initialized your Grid (basically after initializing it). To make sure add it in a document ready handler below the grid.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you can just write your own custom cell template for whatever buttons you want to add on and stick that into your row template.

```
var template = "<div class='btn-group' style='text-align: center'>" +
               "<a class='btn btn-mini' rel='tooltip' title='Edit' href=''><i class='icon-edit'></i></a>" +
               "<a class='btn btn-mini' rel='tooltip' title='Create' href=''><i class='icon-tasks'></i></a>" +
               "<a class='btn btn-mini' rel='tooltip' title='Delete' href=''><i class='icon-trash'></i></a>"+
               "</div>";
columns.push({title: '', width: 100,template: template, filterable: false, sortable:false, groupable:false});
```

The above would render for all rows.  Any other javascript you want to add on to the overall behaviour of the buttons after they are rendered could be added to dataBound attribute.

Does this help answer your question?

Comment: The buttons already exist and are part of the standard kendo grid but I'm trying to add code to them rather than create new buttons.